# reference a fla component in an actionscript project?

Tags: actionscript-3

How do I reference a fla component from an actionscript project? I use flex builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the answer depends on what component you are using, but inside flash IDE toggle the option of exporting the component to actionscript, or using the component code libraries should work.